# How to get the result if forgot to name a function or object

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assign

I have a very big function which takes hours to give me the result. I forgot to name it. Is there any way that I can show the result of my function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you forgot to assign the result? As in `sum(x)` instead of `y <- sum(x)`? If so, you're out of luck.

Comment: yes. I forgot to assign a name to it.

Comment: @Roland thanks. It is very big issue.

Comment: On the positive side: You've learned something.

Comment: :) yes. I will not forgot this issue.

Comment: Wait, there might be help. See my A.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can rescue objects from drowning in the console with `.Last.Value`. See the following example.

```
sum(c(2,2,3,4))
#[1] 11
y <- .Last.value
y
#[1] 11
```

We learn from [`?.Last.Value`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/Last.value) that

> The value of the internal evaluation of a top-level R expression is always assigned to `.Last.value` (in `package:base`) before further processing (e.g., printing).

This also works for functions:

```
function(x){
  sqrt(x)
}

.Last.value
# function(x){
#   sqrt(x)
# }
```

**Interesting note from [lmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4895725/lmo) in the comments:**

As a side note, RStudio users can see this value in their environment panel by going to `Tools > Global Options > General` and then checking the box labelled "Show .Last.value in environment listing"